# Javascript Function Passing in as parameter

Tags: javascript

I want to pass some lines of code as parameter.

```
        function t_1()
        {
            var t6 = '';
            ////
            t_2(d1,d2,d3)
        }

        function t_2(c1, c2, c3)
        {
            var t1 = 12;
            if( t1 >12 )
            {
                // some code here
            }

        }

    </script>
```

Here in function t_2(), if conditions is static. But can i pass from t_1(). Like, condition in t_2() depends on t6 value in t_1().

Can i pass `if` condition code or any dynamic variable from t1 that can be executed in t2?

Comment: Outside of your function you can declare a variable? Like var t6 = ''; and then set it in the t_1 function like t6 = 'something'

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: You can pass `t6` as parameter while calling `t_2(d1,d2,d3)` and use it inside `t2`.

Comment: i am okay with negative marking, but at least tell the reason for this marking. so i wont make same mistake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create anonymous function and pass it as an argument.

```
function t1()
{
    var x = 17;
    var f = function(a) { return a > x; }; // value of x is captured here inside f
    //                           ^^^^^^ here is expression you can pass around
    t2(f);
}

function t2(f)
{
    var y = 4;
    if(f(x)) {  //  ->  if(f(4))  ->  if(4>17)
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

eval() could be a  possible solution.
Eg.

```
function t_1(){
  var a=5, b=10;
  //make you statement a string, any type of statement can be made string
  var c = "a+b"; 
  t_2(a,b,c);

}

function t_2(a,b,c){
  var res = eval(c); // here c can be any js statements in String form
}
```

eval() should be used with high precaution as it can make our application vulnerable to hacking. It should be used very selectively in case where we are getting input from the user.